# RSpec with devise - only the first test is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm trying to write a rspec feature test for a page where the user must be logged in with devise.

```
RSpec.feature "User sees items" do
  before(:context) do
    ..
    login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
  end

  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  it "sees 3 items" do
    create_items 1, 2

    visit root_path

    expect(page).to have_css("#total", text: "3")
  end

  it "sees 7 items" do
    create_items 3, 4
    visit root_path

    expect(page).to have_css("#total", text: "7")
  end
end
```

In my `rails_helper` I'm including `include Warden::Test::Helpers`.

But only my first test with value 3 the user is logged in.
The second one there is an devise error `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.` in the `page.body` of the test.

How can I stay logged? Or do I have to log in each time again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `before(:each)`, not `before(:context)`:

```
before(:each) do # <-- !!!!
  # .. 
  login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
end

after(:each) do
  Warden.test_reset!
end
```

Your problem is that the `before(:context)` is only running *once* - i.e. before the first test runs, whereas the `after(:each)` is running for each test.

Therefore after the first test runs, you've signed out and are not signing back in.

Comment: So that means that the authentization must run again before each `it`, right? I cannot log in just once?

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, you **could** use `before(:context)` and `after(:context)`, or even `before(:all)` and `after(:all)`. This would slightly optimise the tests, but the performance gain is probably insignificant; it's typically better to just return the test suite to a consistent state after each test runs. YMMV. Just be consistent either way.

Comment: @o..o
This solution worked for you? I'm having a very similar trouble.  

I used `before :all` and `after :all`, and the first `it` statement worked but the second `it` statement resulted in user being signed out.  

Changing to `before :each` and `after :each` makes both `it` statements to fail due to the user being logged out.

Comment: @udi I suggest opening a new question, with a [mcve] of the problem. It's very hard to diagnose an issue like this, based only on a summarised comment; it could be caused by many different things.