# Devise & RSpec - the user is signed in only in the first test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I'm writing a spec for a RESTFul controller I have using RSpec and I need to log in the user via Devise.

The following code results in the user being signed in properly in the first `it` statement, but not the second.

If I change `before` and `after` from `:all` to `:each`, both statements fail as if the user is not logged in.

```
RSpec.describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  describe '#index' do
    before :all do
      @account = create(:account)
      @user = @account.users.first
      sign_in(@user)
    end

    after :all do
      sign_out(@user)
    end

    it 'should load all objects of a @user' do
      get :index

      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(body['data'].length).to eq(4)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end

    it 'should load all objects of a @user' do
      get :index

      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(body['data'].length).to eq(4)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

I found few answers to this issue, one being using Cookie Store in tests ENV (which didn't fix it) and also this one [RSpec with devise - only the first test is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720669/rspec-with-devise-only-the-first-test-is-logged-in/48720837) which also didn't help me with the issue.

RSpec 3.7
Rails 5.2
Devise 4.4

Help will be highly appreciated! thanks

Comment: do you use databasecleaner? if so evertything is wiped out after each test

Comment: @apneadiving I am, it's done in `config.before(:suite)`

Comment: Shouldn't you use `before(:each)` in this case? Otherwise Database cleaner will clear the login.

Comment: @bo-oz `before :each` doesn't work as well.  

I've disabled DB Cleaner and still - same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ActAsTenant, do not forget to put ActAsTenant.current_tenant = nil, at the beginning of the before(:each). That caused to me the same problem that you are discribing